# How do I turn away wild Pokémon on Isle Abeens?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

My Isle Abeens has had the same three wild Pokémon for more than a week now, despite me refusing to let them join multiple times. How do I turn them away so that other Pokémon may join?

Comment: Can you just let them join then release them? I haven't really used PokePelago yet

Comment: @Robotnik I haven't done it, but there's no reason I wouldn't be able to. I'm just looking for a way to bypass that.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what three Pokémon won't leave? I'm assuming they're not very good.

Comment: @Vemonus Pikipek, Magnemite, and Gastly.

Comment: don't fill the box with beans

Comment: @Pyritie That doesn't stop Pokémon from visiting and doesn't turn away Pokémon asking to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to turn away a Pokémon is to never tap them when they're visiting Isle Abeens and they still have a question mark over their head. If you've already tapped the Pokémon while it was visiting, it will not leave on its own and will have to be recruited and then released. This is not a problem since tapping a Pokémon doesn't provide any additional information.